# How would you refer to / search on this Alpine region?

Tags: austria, alps, bavaria, geography, local-knowledge

Alpine Locals, noticing the area I have shaded in Photoshop ...

[image]

I'm totally confused whether that would be the "North Tirol", "southern German Tirol", Oberammergauer, Unterammergau, cis-Austrian-German alps, very-far-eastern Swiss alps, Uber-Lech, Füssen Alpine Region, southern lakeland, western Brenner, or what - sorry for my ignorance.

Goal: I'm trying to find an "inn or family-run hotel, with excellent food", in that general area.  I usually start with Tripadvisor for this sort of thing, but I feel it's whole map/search system works, unfortunately, much better for "cities" than regions;  so, in trying to google generally for "inn with excellent food in _ _ _" I plain don't know what to put, in any language.

(Since there's a good number of German-language internauts, I'd usually try to search for this in German - but again I'm mystified what you alpine dudes refer to this area as - perhaps "What you'd say in German" is better here, I don't know. Often there's just plain "more English results" even in specific language areas.)

So, in short, what's the best term for the shaded area, and/or how would I perform the search in question? Thanks.

Comment: Some of that is in Germany and some of it is in Austria. Wouldn't that make it cover several regions?

Comment: I believe that is the Allgäu, but I'm not sure if that and your region cover each other exactly

Comment: Hey Liam! around the alps many designations (say, "burgundy" or "the alps") cover many modern countries...

Comment: @JoeBlow Modern-day Burgundy is entirely within France.

Comment: the ducs would be shocked!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The western half of what you're looking at would fall well within the range usually referred to as Allgäu - [here is a 'map'](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allg%C3%A4u#mediaviewer/Datei:Karte_von_Oberschwaben.png) of the outlines of that region as used in today's tourism industry, covering both Germany and Austria although originally Allgäu was a part of the German Oberschwaben, [see here](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allg%C3%A4u#mediaviewer/Datei:Karte_von_Oberschwaben.png).

The Austrian areas are part of (Nord)Tirol - a map with names of parts of Tirol is [here](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tirol#mediaviewer/Datei:Tirol-Suedtirol-Trentino.png) - and sub-regions of the Austrian Tirol are found [here](http://www.tirolarena.at/tirol.html).

The German areas are all part of the German region of [Oberbayern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_Bavaria) although that stretches much further north than you want to look. Looking at the Landkreise in that region will be quite tedious, but gives fine grain control over where you're looking at. These are the Landkreise bordering Austria in that region (a [map is here](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Bavaria_BGL.svg)):

- Garmisch-Partenkirchen
- Bad Tölz-Wolfratshausen
- Miesbach
- Rosenheim
- Traunstein
- Berchtesgadener Land

Comment: This is indeed the Allgäu, but looking for hotels in the Landkreise you listed would be counterproductive. They are farther east, and travelling to the Allgäu from them is tedious, especially considering the frequent traffic jams on the A8.

Comment: @rumtscho true, apart from Garmisch-Partenkirchen they are further east - but that's why I linked the map.

Comment: sorry I forgot to **tick** this, @grayshade!  seasons greets

Answer (score 3):

The bit you have shaded is not a defined region in itself, as Greyshade has already pointed out. Being a local, I would split the German part into three areas, from West to East:

- Oberallgäu (the area from Isny to just East of Kempten);
- Ostallgäu (the area from just East of Kempten to the Lech); and
- Pfaffenwinkel.

There would be no combined name for the area, since it is composed of two distinctly different regions with different dialects and different customs that do not see each other as belonging together: The Allgäu region belongs to the Swabian dialect area and the Pfaffenwinkel is the South-Easternmost corner of the Bavarian dialect region within Germany. You will notice a rather sharp change in the locals’ speech once you cross the Lech river.

The downside of searching for something in the Allgäu — especially the Ostallgäu, eastern Allgäu — is that it does extend a fair bit further North, away from the alps. If you are looking for something within the alpine region, i.e. close to the mountains, try *Allgäuer Alpen* (Allgäu Alps).

---

The bit of Austria you marked also is rather interesting. While nominally beloinging to Tyrol it is typically referred to as the Außerfern — it is *außerhalb* (behind) the Fernpass when viewed from the rest of Tyrol. Interestingly, the dialect in the Außerfern is also of the Swabian type and it is the only bit of Austria that features Swabian. (Vorarlbergian is an Alemannic dialect, not a Swabian one.)

---

In any case my hat is off for going on holiday in this incredibly beautiful region, no matter whether it is the Allgäu, the Außerfern or the Pfaffenwinkel.